# Who was this spren going to choose?

Tags: cosmere, stormlight-archive

At the end of *Oathbringer*, Hoid grabs a spren (a Cryptic, it seems) from the ruined Alethi palace.

> “I know you’d rather have someone else,” Wit said, “but it isn’t the
> time to be picky. I’m certain now that the reason I’m in the city is
> to find you.”
>
> <sub>*Oathbringer*</sub>

I get the strong impression that we’re supposed to know who this spren was meant for, but I can’t figure it out. Surely not Aesudan?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Elhokar

Brandon Sanderson has said that Elhokar would have been a Lightweaver had he finished the first ideal.

> **Q:** If Elhokar had been able to finish his sentence, what type would he be?
>
> **A:** He would have been a Lightweaver.
> <sub>[Oathbringer London Signing](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/256-oathbringer-london-signing/#e8711)</sub>

This basically confirms that the Cryptic would have bonded Elhokar.

Comment: This has been pretty clear for a while.  I don't remember if it was late in the first book or early in the second, but there's a point where Elhokar complains about being haunted by symbol-headed creatures.  Once you realize what's happening to Shallan, it's immediately clear that Elhokar is destined to become a Lightweaver as well.  (Unless something goes terribly wrong of course!)

Answer (score 9):

### Almost certainly Elhokar

1. Hoid finds this spren at the palace. I doubt it was for Aesudan (she wasn’t really on that path) or for her and Elhokar’s son (he’s a little too young to become a Radiant, I suspect).
2. During the battle at the palace, Elhokar was about to say the First Ideal:

   > Elhokar had fallen to his knees. In one arm he held his terrified son,
   >   in the other hand he held … a sheet of paper? A sketch?
   >
   > Kaladin could almost hear Elhokar stuttering the words.
   >
   > *Life … life before death …*
   >
   > The hair on Kaladin’s neck rose. Elhokar started to glow softly.
   >
   > *Strength … before weakness …*
   >
   > “Do it, Elhokar,” Kaladin whispered.
   >
   > *Journey. Journey before …*
   >
   > <sub>*Oathbringer*</sub>

   We’ve seen before that someone’s spren tends to come along before they say the First Ideal.

   Elhokar failed, though, which presumably traumatized the spren (which is why it was still around).

   There wouldn’t really be any other reason for the spren to hang around.